# Determine the conditional extreme for $u = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ for $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Determine the conditional extreme for $u = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ for $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$.

Using Lagrange's multipliers we get:

$$<2x, 2y, 2z> = \lambda<\frac{2x}{a^2}, \frac{2y}{b^2}, \frac{2z}{c^2}>$$

concluding $\lambda = \frac{1}{a^2} = \frac{1}{b^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} \rightarrow a^2=b^2=c^2$. If so, then this provides the condition that :

$$<x,y,z> = \frac{\lambda}{a^2}<{x}, {y}, z>$$

Then either $<x,y,z> = <0,0,0>$ or $\lambda = a^2$ (or both).  I can't seem to conclude an extrema condition from this. What am I missing?

Comment: I think it is much easier to think about this geometrically. You are the surface of an ellipsioid, what is the furthest and closest you get to the origin?

Comment: $x = \pm a$ would be the farthest but I am more interested in a formal solution using lagrange.

Comment: Lagrange Multiplier method will not give you extrema if they happen at points on the boundary. There are no critical points meeting the constraint. Points on the boundary must be checked separately. So you must check $(\pm a, 0, 0), (0, \pm b, 0), (0, 0, \pm c)$. We do not know for sure that $a \gt b \gt c$. Conditional extrema would mean one of these points is the maxima and one of them is minima.

Answer (score 1):

$a,b,c$ are all constants so you cannot conclude that they are all equal. What you can conclude from your four equations is that either

- $\lambda = a^2, y = z = 0$, $x = \pm a$
- $\lambda = b^2, x = z = 0$, $y = \pm b$
- $\lambda = c^2, x = y = 0$, $z = \pm c$

Then, you can take the maximum of $a,b,c$ and get your extrema conditions.